# Why doesn't IntelliJ code autocomplete work?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I try to use the code autocomplete of IntelliJ by using `ctrl+space` it doesn't work.

What do I need to do?

For example, in this code I want to use the add method of List and it doesn't give me the option to.

[image]

Comment: This might happen if the file is not in a source directory

Comment: What does it mean? What i need to do to solve it?

Comment: Can you show us your project structure?

Comment: does your project build successfully? Build->Make Project, does it run?

Comment: BTW. A `hash % 360` might be negative when `hash` is negative.

Answer (score 7):

Several possible reasons:

1. Your file doesn't reside in a content root and is not [bound to a build path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#specify_output_path), so it doesn't get the required class definitions and resources needed for code completion. To fix, right click your root source directory -> Mark Directory As -> [Sources Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories).
2. Check to see if you accidentally turned on the Power Save mode (**File | Power Save Mode**). Turning it on minimizes power consumption of your laptop by eliminating the background operations, including error highlighting, on-the-fly inspections, and code completion. Turn it off.
3. Make sure the JDK for your project is [set up correctly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html) in the **File | Project Structure** window.
4. A file containing classes and methods that you want to appear in completion suggestions list is marked as a plain text file. To fix, right-click on the file -> Mark as Java class.
5. External libraries that contain methods that you want to appear in the completion suggestions list are not [added as dependencies or global libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html).