# Intellij C# Code is not autoscripting Unity methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellij-idea

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something (probably, honestly), but for some reason Intellij is not giving me a list of options for autocompletion when I program using something (eg. a method) from Unity. For example:

Input.GetKeyDown() will never autocomplete. This is somewhat of a problem for me as I'm just learning Unity, and it's hard to naturally find my way around since I can't look at all the options I have.

Tried all the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777308/why-the-intellij-code-autocomplete-doesnt-work) post.

Comment: Intellij is an IDE for Java and Kotlin. Why not download Visual Studio

Comment: Use VScode if you are looking for a light weight alternative.